# Logback is unable to recognize variable substitution for scanPeriod properties

Tags: java, logback

I am trying to use variable substitution for the `scanPeriod` property such that i can have multiple environment files.

It seems like Logback is unable to recognize [variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) for certain properties.

For example the `scanPeriod` property:

Logback configuration:

```
<configuration scan="${scan:-true}" scanPeriod="${scan-interval:-10 minutes}">
```

Specified to take default value of 10 minutes of logback property is not defined.

Logback properties:

```
scan=true
scan-interval=30 seconds
```

This property should override the default configuration of 10 minutes.

Logback error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String value [${scan-interval:-10 minutes}] is not in the expected format.
```

According to the [Duration API](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/util/Duration.html), the duration format is correct.

This is using:

- slf4j 1.6.2
- logback classis 0.9.30
- logback core 0.9.30

EDIT: **Filed a Jira report** for this - http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-307

UPDATE: 
28 Dec 2011 This is marked as a Major, and looked at by Ceki Gulcu. :D

UPDATE:
12 Jun 2012 Still no updates. Left comment in JIRA.

UPDATE:
12 July 2012 Accepted as a valid bug. To fix in 1.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-396

Accepted as a valid bug and to be fixed in 1.0.7

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Duration API](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/util/Duration.html) that you posted, you can also use (without the space):

```
<configuration scan="${scan:-true}" scanPeriod="${scan-interval:-10minutes}">

private static final Pattern DURATION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(DOUBLE_PART
                              + "\\s*" + UNIT_PART, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, yepp.